# onchange function is Not working in angular js

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, onchange

i have one dropdown and textbox called office name and pincode .if i change pincode it should change in drop down office name.for one pincode there can be multiple office name

```
onChangePincode() {
  let selectedPinData;
  let pincode
  for (let i = 0; i < this.pincodeDetails.length; i++) {
    if (pincode == this.pincodeDetails[i].pincode) {
      //console.log(this.pincodeDetails[i])
      selectedPinData = this.pincodeDetails[i];
      //console.log(selectedPinData)
      this.pincodeData.push(this.pincodeDetails[i]);
      // console.log(this.pincodeDetails[i])
    }
  }
}

this.pincodeDetails = [{
  id: 1,
  officeName: 'basaveshwara',
  divisionName: 'Basaveshwarnagar',
  regionName: 'North Karnatka',
  circleName: 'karnatka',
  pincode: '560059'
}, {
  id: 2,
  officeName: 'basaveshwara',
  divisionName: 'Vijaynagar',
  regionName: 'North Karnatka',
  "circleName": 'karnatka',
  pincode: '560079'
}, {
  id: 4,
  officeName: 'Malleshwaram',
  divisionName: 'Rajajinagar',
  regionName: 'south Karnatka',
  circleName: 'karnatka',
  pincode: '560059'
}, {
  id: 1,
  officeName: 'basaveshwara',
  divisionName: 'Basaveshwarnagar',
  regionName: 'North Karnatka',
  circleName: 'karnatka',
  pincode: '560078'
}]
```

and i have written json please refer

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear from the OP as to what exactly you're looking for. But I think what you want is that the options in the Select List change when you change the pin code in the text field.

If that's what you really want, here's what you can do:

```
onChangePincode(pincode) {
  this.pincodeData = this.pincodeDetails.filter(office => office.pincode.includes(pincode));
}
```

And in your template, you can call this method on `keyup` event on the text input:

```
For Office Name
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="null" disabled>Select an Office</option>
  <option *ngFor="let datum of pincodeData" value="datum.id">{{ datum.officeName }}</option>
</select>

<br><br>

For Pincde
<input type="text" #pincode (keyup)="onChangePincode(pincode.value)">
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-text-input-change-dropdown-list-items?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: thank you but im using kendo-dropdownList  its not working for it   
 
 <label for="Name"  class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-10 col-12 text-right custom-left" >Office Name:</label>
  <kendo-dropdownlist  
  formControlName="officeName"
  [data]="pincodeData"
  [textField]="'officeName'"
  [valueField]="'id'"
  type="text"
  class="form-control col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-10 col-sm-10 mb-input" 
  
  >
  </kendo-dropdownlist

Comment: @swagath, I won't be able to help in that case without a Sample StackBlitz. If possible, please create one.